# .Net 2 version of Element At

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections

I'm trying to recreate a piece of code that I originally wrote in .net 4 so that it would work in .Net 2

The piece of code in question is below, and the line that causes the problems is the one in the middle of the For next block. The specific error being that ElementAt is not a member of system.collections.Generic.List(Of String).

```
Public Function GetListOfAvailableC1Themes() As List(Of String)
    Dim lPath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Themes"
    Dim lThemeList As New List(Of String)
    If Not Directory.Exists(lPath) Then
        Throw New DirectoryNotFoundException("Could not find the 'Themes' directory.")
    Else
        Dim lst As New List(Of String)
        lst.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(lPath))
        For i As Integer = 0 To lst.Count - 1
            lThemeList.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(lst.ElementAt(i)))
        Next
        Return lThemeList
    End If

End Function
```

Obviously I've realised that this probably wasn't introduced until .Net3.5 at the earliest.

So what would one have done prior to that in .net 2.0 to achieve the same result?

Thanks

Comment: You're right in that the [`Enumerable.ElementAt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb299233(v=vs.90).aspx) extension method was added later, it's introduced in .NET 3.5. Just use the lists's indexer (`lst(i)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the indexer e.g.

```
lst(i)
```

Or

```
lst.item(i)
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, just the ticket

Answer (score 0):

`ElementAt(index)` is valid in any class that implements `IEnumerable` interface. So, it's valid for `List(Of T)`, but in `List(Of T)` you also can use the `index` directly, for sample `list(index)`, and you will get the object in this index. In `IEnumerable` is not a indexed collection, that's the reason for `ElementAt` method exists.